# making a list using inner query in Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, subquery

I am trying to create a sublist using Linq but don't understand the error in this. I don't think i am doing wrong but i think others eye will help me to sort this issue.

```
var dataList = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
 dataList = from line in dataList
              let temp = from data in line.Split(';').ToList()
                         where line.Split(';').ToList().IndexOf(data) != 0 ||line.Split(';').ToList().IndexOf(data) != 1
                          select data
                          select string.Join(",",temp);
```

I am getting error saying that IEnumerable list cannot be implicitly converted to string[]..:(

Comment: Add ToList on the end

Comment: No. thats not helping. Actually the complete collection is IEnumerable, I mean dataList is.

Comment: @Derek: OP doesn't have a `List`, it is a `string[]`

Comment: If you used two separate variables and declared their types explicitly, it would be obvious to you what the problem was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dataList` is an array, while LINQ returns `IEnumerable<string>`. Add `ToArray` to the end of the query:

```
dataList = (from line in dataList
            let temp = from data in line.Split(';').ToList()
                        where line.Split(';').ToList().IndexOf(data) != 0 || line.Split(';').ToList().IndexOf(data) != 1
                        select data
            select string.Join(",", temp)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to compile that code you posted I get the following exception:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string[]'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Reason is that you are trying to reuse dataList, but the return types of File.ReadAllLines and string.Join methods don't match. This fixes it:

```
dataList = (from line in dataList
                   let temp = from data in line.Split(';').ToList()
                              where line.Split(';').ToList().IndexOf(data) != 0 || line.Split(';').ToList().IndexOf(data) != 1
                              select data
                   select string.Join(",", temp)).ToArray();
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

What version of the .NET Framework are you on?
The overload of `String.Join` that takes an `IEnumerable<string>` was only introduced in v4.0.
If you're on an earlier version it's trying to take that `IEnumerable<string>` and use it as a `string[]`.

Also (this doesn't fix your problem) I think the `||` in the 4th line should be a `&&`.